# MVC Model get() and set() vs. straight-up $model->var = val

Tags: php, model-view-controller

When is the right time to use functions to set variables inside of my models, verse simply directly assigning them?

AKA...

When do I use:

```
$model->set('status','active');
```

...instead of:

```
$model->status = 'active';
```

Comment: This depends on you MVC framework. Which one are you using?

Comment: rolling my own...for the learning process mainly

Comment: You should also consider `$model->setStatus('active')` . Putting all logic into one `set` method is not very good either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using getters and setters is good for the encapsulation of code. It's always a good idea to use them.

Think about this:

- What if your model has some variables that you don't want to be able to be read or changed (or both)?
- What if you ever need to do something besides just getting and setting the variable? (for example, sanatizing data)?

Comment: Encapsulation also is extremely useful when debugging. Using getters and setters lets you track changes to variables easily and in only one place, rather than having to find everywhere in you code that you called $model->variable

Comment: ah, i see...that definitely makes sense:)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of PHP (5.x), you can get the best of both worlds with the magic methods `__get()` and `__set()`.  [(PHP reference)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).  Any access to an undefined property will be routed to the appropriate get/set function automatically.

I must admin that I'm not certain if this is really a good idea to use or not, but it seems like a decent fit for a base model class in a MVC system.